# Candy distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

There are $2n$ boxes of candy, $n$ of which belong to $A$ and other $n$ to $B$. Each of the boxes contain $a_i$ and $b_i$ candies respectively. These candies are to be distributed among $s$ number of students. It is known that $\sum{b_i}= s$. Each student gets exactly one candy, no less and no more. Whenever a candy is to be given to a student, one of the boxes (non-empty) is chosen at random and candy is withdrawn from it. If after withdrawing the candy the box becomes empty, it is discarded (and hence not used in probability calculation at later stage). What is the probability that **all** of $A's$ candies remain as is?

My (**incorrect**) try:

Let $$n=\sum{b_i+a_i}$$
Consider the distribution of $a_i$s and $b_i$s. There are $n$ slots to fill. What I want is the probability that the first $s$ slots are filled by $b_i$s. Thus,
$$ans = \frac{\frac{s!}{\prod{b_i}}*\frac{(n-s)!}{\prod{a_i}}}{\frac{n!}{\prod{b_i}*\prod{a_i}}}$$
which can be simplified to
$$ans = \frac{1}{{n}\choose{s}}$$
But, this is incorrect.

Consider $n = 2, A = \{1, 1\}, B = \{2, 1\}$.

Then, answer should be:

$(b_1,b_1,b_2), (b_1,b_2,b_1), (b_2,b_1,b_1) = 1/4*1/4*1/3 + 1/4*1/4*1/3 + 1/4*1/3*1/3 =  
 \frac{5}{72}$, but, my formula gives it to be $\frac{1}{10}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I'm sorry but I didn't understand how to begin with it

Comment: You'll be much more likely to get a quality answer if you can show some work on the problem, even in the form of an attempt that totally didn't work.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery ok I'll add now

Comment: @AaronMontgomery done

Comment: @mike: For your assigned problem, do you have specific values for $n,\{a_1,..,a_n\},\{b_1,...,b_n\}$?

Comment: @quasi no, i don't

Comment: First of all, if $n=4$, there should be 8 total boxes of candy, so your example would be referring to $n=2$, correct? Also, I don't know why you're saying $\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: @mike: Where is the problem from? What course? Is it from a book? Is it a programming problem?

Comment: @AlvinChen Yes, $n = 2$. I'm sorry about that, I was working with different examples and mixed those. Updating

Comment: @quasi it's a programming problem

Comment: @mike: Where is the problem from? Is it from a programming competition?

Comment: @quasi No, a friend of mine asked me a couple of days ago. I was unable to figure out the solution, and hence asked here

Comment: @mike: A closed form is unlikely. It can be computed recursively, but it's more of a programming problem than a math problem.

Comment: @mike: Also, it has the feel of a programming challenge from a website. If it's an ongoing competition, it's not fair to ask for help.

Comment: @quasi it isn't. I'll delete the post if you saw this/similar question in any contest

Comment: @mike: How do you know it's not? Please ask your friend where the problem comes from.

Comment: @mike: I implemented a recursive solution in Maple, but I won't post it without knowing where the problem comes from.

Comment: @quasi Weird...